# Gitea runner repository cache between workflows

Tags: continuous-integration, gitea

Is there any way to cache the checked out repository between workflow runs with Gitea runner?
Let's say repository uses a lot of rarely modified LFS objects and it's too slow to checkout from scratch each time. GitLab runner does "Reinitialized existing Git repository..." in this case, so most of the data is persistent and getting reused. Is there any way to achieve the same behavior with Gitea runner?